# How check which variable is sent to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a Javascript AJAX function that can send some data (to a MongoDB database)f
. The database only consists of one document which keeps track of the total amount of questions answered and also the number of questions answered correctly.

The function can take either of these numbers (updated in different places in the code), but how do I check which number it is inside of the function? It would look something like this:

```
function updateQuestionsProgress(number) {
//TODO Check which of the two numbers is sent
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/statistics/quick_test",
    data : theNumber,

    error:function(msg, string){
        console.log(msg);
    },

    success:function(data){
        alert("sd");}
    });
```

Knowing which number it is, I could then update it accordingly in that URL middleware.

Am I better of just doing two different functions instead? Seems very inconvenient if you have a very large database and you just want to update part of a document.

Comment: ?? what does this mean? You've got `number` set up as a parameter. Can't you just check that? It is not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: The number can either be x or y. I want to do different things to the number depending on which one it is. I want to check the name of the variable that is sent into the function, or something along those lines.

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: So I need two different functions then? Let's say my database document have 10 different values and they are all updated one by one in different locations. 10 different functions would then be required?

Comment: uh, if (number == x) { } else if (number == y) { }

Comment: Just alter you function to accept another parameter.

Comment: `10 different functions would then be required?`  If that was the case your code needs a serious refactor.. :)

Comment: @Keith How would it be done then? I'm not very clever. My database document has 10 values: entry1, entry2... etc, all being some number. And then entry6 is updated, so you need to call the database via the Ajax function. What parameters do you give this function and how do you check that entry6 is incoming?

Comment: You don't check if entry6 is incoming, you make whatever is calling decide..  It's really hard to help without more code, eg. were your calling this function from.  You talk about `seems so clunky` in one of the answers, but I can't think of anything more clunky that a function doing something different depending on were it was called from.

Comment: If that is the case then your Ajax request would need to send more information i.e. data : {'qNo': qstNumber, 'Answer':theNumber,'Correct':isCorrect}. Then in the server side of things you have the field to work with and the information necessary to store a value for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the caller of the function to tell you which number it is.
You can send a string a bool flag (since it's just two options), or an object.

```
function updateQuestionsProgress(dataObj) {
//TODO Check which of the two numbers is sent
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/statistics/quick_test",
    data : dataObj,
```

When you call `updateQuestionsProgress(dataObj)` you can pass whatever object you like to the function. E.x. `var dataObj = {"answers" : 5, "correct_answers": 3}` and anything else you need.

Comment: Yeah, I began doing this but with an object. Just seems so clunky, especially if there would be many more options.

Comment: Did you mean that you are sending an object like `var obj = { "answers" : 7}` into the function. Because it can be extended. At the end you are sending a post request - it may contain many keys and values. Going with your object approach might be the best solution.